# Деструктор удаляет дважды один и тот же адрес, из-за чего происходит сбой программы при перемножении матриц

Tags: c++, указатели, матрицы, перегрузка-операторов, оператор-присваивания

У меня такая проблема: я написал код для перемножения двух матриц. Для этого я создал класс, в котором объявил поля матрицы, функцию считывания с файла, записи и перегрузку оператора умножения.

Вроде все работало. Но преподаватель сказал, что в классе должен обязательно быть деструктор. В общем, после того, как я написал деструктор, стал происходить сбой программы. Как я понял, проблема в том, что деструктор дважды удаляет один и тот же адрес. Как мне закодировать, чтоб программа работала с деструктором? Я не очень понимаю. Помогите пожалуйста править код.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Matrix {
private:
void method();

private:
double** matr; //matrix
int rown; //rown
int column; //column

std::string m_name;
public:
Matrix(const char *name)
{
    m_name = name;

    matr = NULL;
    rown = column = 0;

    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " CONSTRUCTOR " << m_name.data() << " " << matr << endl;
}

void allocate(int in_rown, int in_column)
{
    rown = in_rown;
    column = in_column;

    matr = new double*[rown];
    for (int i = 0; i < rown; i++) {
        matr[i] = new double[column];
    }

    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " ALLOCATOR " << m_name.data() << " " << matr << endl;
}

Matrix operator*(Matrix & mult);
void read_matrix(const char*filename);
void write_matrix(const char*filename) const;

~Matrix()
{
    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " DESTRUCTOR " << m_name.data() << " " << matr << endl;

    if (matr != NULL) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rown; i++) {
            delete[] matr[i];
        }

        delete[] matr;
    }
}
};

Matrix Matrix::operator*(Matrix & mult) {
Matrix result("result");


result.allocate(rown, mult.column);

for (int i = 0; i < result.rown; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < result.column; k++)
    {
        result.matr[i][k] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < result.column; j++)
        {
            result.matr[i][k] += matr[i][j] * mult.matr[j][k];
        }
    }
}

return result;
}

void Matrix::read_matrix(const char* filename) {
ifstream in(filename);

in >> rown;
in >> column;

allocate(rown, column);

//Считаем матрицу из файла
for (int i = 0; i < rown; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
        in >> matr[i][j];

in.close();
return;
}

void Matrix::write_matrix(const char* filename) const {
ofstream on(filename);

on << rown << '\t' << column << endl;

//запишем матрицу в файл
for (int i = 0;i < rown;i++) {
    for (int k = 0;k < column;k++) {
        on << matr[i][k] << '\t';
    }
    on << endl;
}

on.close();
return;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
if (argc == 4) {

    Matrix input1("input1");
    Matrix input2("input2");
    input1.read_matrix(argv[1]);
    input2.read_matrix(argv[2]);

    Matrix a("a");
    a = input1*input2;
    /*Matrix b;*/
    a.write_matrix(argv[3]);
}
system("pause");
return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

В этом предложении

```
a = input1*input2;
```

используется созданный компилятором по умолчанию копирующий оператор присваивания, который результат перемножения двух матриц - временный объект этого же класса - присваивает объекту `a`.

Определенный компилятором копирующий оператор присваивания просто по-членно копирует данные одного объекта в другой. В результате в выше приведенном предложении два объекта будут иметь копии указателей друг друга.

После выполнения этого присвоения временный объект будет удален, и для него будет вызван деструктор, который освободит выделенную память.

Когда будет удаляться объект `a`, для него также будет вызван деструктор, который попытаетеся освободить уже освобожденную память по тому же самому адресу.

Когда вы имеете дело с указателями в классе и вручную выделяете память, адресуемую этими указателями, то вам надо написать в явном виде помимо деструктора по крайней мере также конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания, которые будут делать "глубокую" копию объектов.

Для вашего конкретного примера, чтобы ваш код выполнялся без описанной ошибки, будет достаточно написать перемещающий оператор присваивания.

Например,

```
Matrix & operator =( Matrix &&rhs )
{
    if ( this != &rhs )
    {
        std::swap( this->rown, rhs.rown );
        std::swap( this->column, rhs.column );
        std::swap( this->matr, rhs.matr );
    }

    return *this;
}
```